# how can I transform a 1D matrix to another one, by two element of the second matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Does anyone know how can I transform a 1D matrix to another one, just by 2 elements of second matrix?

M1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]         =>       M2 = [20 n1' n2' n3' n4' n5' 30]

for example,In above matrices how can I find the value of n1' , n2' , . . . , n5' ?

Sincerely

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @cooper.hat , I update the question and describe more details. now how can I find transform coefficient to convert M1 to M2?

Comment: Usually, to "transform" one vector to another, we multiply by a matrix.  $m_1$ is one row by seven columns, and so is $m_2$.  So perhaps you are looking for a matrix $A$ such that $m_2$ = $m_1 A$?  Is that your question, maybe?  Here, $A$ would be seven rows by seven columns.

Comment: Or perhaps you want $m_2 = \alpha m_1 + b$ where $\alpha$ is a scalar (one by one) and $b$ is a one by seven vector?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are not clear what type of transformation you are looking at. For example M2=0*M1+[20 0 0 0 0 0 30] or M2=0*M1+[20 0 1 0 42 0 30] would both work